# pyramid.arima Anaconda 3 Installation ERROR

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, anaconda3

I am using

- macOS 10.12.6
- Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7
- JupiterLab 0.35.4
- I have used the following [GitHub project](https://github.com/advaitsave/Introduction-to-Time-Series-forecasting-Python)

I have tried the following installations

- `!pip install pyramid-arima`
- `!pip install pmdarima`

So I can use

- `from pyramid.arima import auto_arima`

ERROR `!pip install pmdarima`

```
DOWNLOADED PACKAGES REACHED 100% for all
....
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/computer/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/rk/cd2m2z5s3cdfx12h9ltqk3500000gn/T/pip-build-env-vu2njaj5/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel cython>=0.29.14 "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.5'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.6'" "numpy==1.16.1; python_version=='3.7'" "numpy==1.17.5; python_version>='3.8'" scipy>=1.0:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

  ----------------------------------------

Command "/Users/computer/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 
/private/var/folders/rk/cd2m2z5s3cdfx12h9ltqk3500000gn/T/pip-build-env-vu2njaj5/overlay --no-warn-script-
location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 
cython>=0.29.14 "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.5'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.6'" 
"numpy==1.16.1; python_version=='3.7'" "numpy==1.17.5; python_version>='3.8'" scipy>=1.0" failed with
 error code 1 in None
```

`from pyramid.arima import auto_arima`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyramid.arima'`

Comment: Have you  created a file `enum.py` by any chance??

Comment: Where Should I look for that? It defiantly does not have any in the Jupiter notebook's library

Comment: try typing `import enum` followed by `print(enum.__file__)` and report the result

Comment: yep it has it ```/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/enum.py```

Comment: That is the one that should be there. Can you open it? Does it also contain the class `IntFlag`, or is it empty?

Comment: It has ```class IntFlag(int, Flag):```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `pyramid.arima` is a depreciated expression at python 3.7
  Anaconda
- I have opened up anaconda promt as a system admin
- than I have installed `conda install -c saravji pmdarima`